# Laravel not able to display relationship name instead of id, even though defined as relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have defined relation between books and authors in my Laravel application like so:

my Book Model:

```
class Book extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'books';

    protected $fillable = [
        'ISBN', 'publisher_id', 'author_id', 'year', 'title', 'price',
    ];

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
    }
}
```

And here is my BookController index:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('books.index', [
        'books' => DB::table('books')->paginate(15)
    ]);
}
```

So now i want to display the author name instead of the author_id in my view:

```
@foreach ($books as $book)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $book->author->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

But i keep getting the error:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$author (View: index.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'books' => DB::table('books')->paginate(15)
```

when you use db, you are dealing with query builder, not eloquent query builder!

you have to use the model itself and load the relation:

```
'books' => Book::with(['author'])->paginate(15);
```